# Getting Value outside tag with web scraper JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I'm attempting to create a scraper broken into two classes. One being a backend that will scrap a value from a website & return it the another calling class where for now it'll be printed. My problem is I'm stuck when it comes to getting a value defined outside a tag. I.e. `<div class="temp">13</div>`

Here is my backend so far, it takes a url in the get function in the event I want to add more classes that use it in the future

```
const PORT = 8000
const axios = require('axios')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')
const url = require("url");
app.use(cors())

app.get('/temp/:url1', (req, res) => {
    axios(url1)
        .then(response => {
            const html = response.data
            const $ = cheerio.load(html)
            const value = []
            
            *stuck here*
          
        }).catch(err => console.log(err))

})

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server running on PORT ${PORT}`))
```

Here is my first app. It's only calling fetch and printing the values

```
url1 = 'https://www.walmart.com/ip/Hind-Boys-Active-Shirts-Shorts-and-Jogger-Pants-8-Piece-Outfit-Set-Sizes-4-16/952146762?athcpid=952146762&athpgid=AthenaHomepageDesktop__gm__-1.0&athcgid=null&athznid=SeasonalCampaigns_d396fb61-c3c0-46db-a4d9-aaf34191b39f_items&athieid=null&athstid=CS020&athguid=kZNrXnatcjxcgUvbKkvbwYMT4bwAapwfOaos&athancid=null&athena=true&athbdg=L1400'
//(in this instance, the value I'm attempting to get is the "Now 24.99" portion)
fetch('http://localhost:8000/temp/' + url1)
    .then(response => {return response.json()})
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

To make it easier here is the HTML from the url

```
<span itemprop="price" aria-hidden="false">Now $24.97</span>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to extract from string `<span itemprop="price" aria-hidden="false">Now $24.97</span>`?

Comment: Probably XPath can help. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_examples.asp

Comment: @VladDX the text "Now $24.97"

Comment: You'll need to [`send` a response](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send), is that your problem?

Comment: @Bergi I'm trying to get the "Now $24.97" text from within the span, I don't think a send is exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: It sounded like you had trouble getting any value to your frontend at all. If that's not the problem, you may as well remove the frontend part from your question

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I am. I'm confused on how I'd get the text within the <span> tags. The only examples I could find reference tags within, such as hrefs. I removed the front end text as I realized I was thinking about it wrong. It's not so much a front end but more a simple calling function

Comment: Is the client able to provide arbitrary URLs to the `temp` route? If so, maybe it's not a good idea to hardcode any cheerio selectors there, and the client should scrape. If the URLs are all supposed to be pointing to a standard set of pages that can all be scraped the same way, then cheerio on the backend proxy makes sense.

Comment: @ggorlen The reason I didn't have the client scrape is in the future if I wanted to expand the code to different urls that had the same HTML key (i.e. more walmart pages) I could do so without having to rewrite the code

Comment: @JustThatGuy93 OK, so you do expect only those URLs. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: @ggorlen Only the urls being passed to the function? Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two options here:

- The server parses the page and returns the price to the client
- The server passes the HTML response to the client, who is responsible for parsing

If the `/temp` (or `/bids`) route is supposed to handle arbitrary URLs, the second option makes more sense. But if the contract with the client is that they're all the same sort of URL, then you can (and probably should) do the scraping on the server:

```js
const axios = require("axios");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const app = require("express")();

const ua =
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36";

app.get("/bids", (req, res) => {
  axios
    .get(req.query.url, {headers: {"User-Agent": ua}})
    .then(({data: html}) => {
      const $ = cheerio.load(html);
      res.json({price: $("[itemprop='price']").text().trim()});
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json({error: "Bad request"}));
});

app.listen(8000, () => console.log("listening on port 8000"));
```

A few things to note:

- You can use `req.query` and pass a query string like `?url=https://www.example.com`. `req.params` seems to be confused by paths like `/bids/https://www.example.com`. It's possible but maybe [ugly](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/blob/34ec83b25ccacad5c523e6b0ad2e156d2107c6e6/lib/cors-anywhere.js#L223)? You could also accept a POST JSON payload with the URL.
- I'm using a user agent string to (help) avoid blocking.
- `[itemprop="price"]` is the CSS selector I'm using for your element. I'm nitpicking, but I'd say the value you want is *inside* the element rather than *outside*. It's the text content of the element (as opposed to an attribute, the `foo="bar"` pairs).
- I'm not really doing much in the way of handling errors, but this is important.

A general tip: try to decompose and minimize your problems and work on one at a time. Getting the URL to the server, making the request and parsing the HTML are all totally different steps. If you haven't validated that your URL parameter is coming through correctly, you might be confused if you're off working on selecting an element on a response that isn't what you think it is.

If you want to focus on Cheerio parsing, temporarily hardcode the HTML to simplify the problem space, avoiding bugs that could be elsewhere in the app getting in the way. Or hardcode the URL if you want to focus on making the request work.

Comment: The /temp/ and /bids/ was a mistype on my part when trying to research before making the question. Temp was obviously just for testing, bid came from a part of a tutorial

Comment: It's not too important as long as you're consistent. Did this code work for you?

Comment: ReferenceError: fetch is not defined for when I try and start the calling class

Comment: Are you running that in the browser or in Node 18+? If not, where are you running it? If you're running it in Node, use axios since you presumably have that installed. That's unrelated to my code here--purely a client error. You could hit this route with a normal browser URL, `http://localhost:8000/bids?url=<your URL>` or curl to establish that it works, then move on to `fetch` later.

Comment: The fetch error came from a bad version of Node. Updated it & my client is giving TypeError:  Dictionary (walmart url) expected to be Null, Undefined, or Object if I do ```fetch("http://localhost:8000/bids/", url)``` and SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 when ```http://localhost:8000/bids/"+url```

Comment: Did you try the URL I gave above in the browser to establish that it works? Then do `fetch("http://localhost:8000/bids?url=<Your URL>")` after you are able to see the response in the browser. It's a different format than your original URL for reasons explained in my post.

Comment: That was the problem, I didn't have the ```?url=``` portion. Thank you.

Comment: In the event I try and scrape a website that has multiple of the same fields i.e. itemprop="price", or class="row field item", how would I handle that?

Comment: Maybe try `[...$("[itemprop='price']")].map(e => $(e).text().trim());`. If it doesn't work, sounds like a good topic for a new question.